What is the difference between django rest_framework "serializers.ValidationError" and "exceptions.ValidationError"
I was wondering, if there are any differences between django rest_framework`s:
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError

as they are imported differentrly.

rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError is used for general validation errors outside of serializers,
while rest_framework.serializers.ValidationError is used specifically for validation errors within serializer classes.
Example of from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError
def my_view(request):
    # Example validation in a view
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise ValidationError("User must be authenticated to access this endpoint")

Example of from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if len(value) < 3:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username must be at least 3 characters long.")
        return value

